# What to grep on result of find function

Tags: grep, find

```
find . -type d -regextype sed -regex ".*some_pattern.*" -exec sh -c 'grep -Ril "find_it" $0' {} \;
```

What I want to achieve here is to narrow down a number of folders against which grep should be run. Apparently, my example doesn't work and fails with

```
find: sh: Key has expired
```

Comment: "Key has expired", are you running in a CIFS mounted directory?

Comment: not sure, probably

Comment: The error has nothing to do with `find` and a search on the error message leads here: https://serverfault.com/questions/63277/mount-cifs-share-gives-mount-error-127-key-has-expired